# How to set PopDelay of HoverMenuExtender from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using `HoverMenuExtender` for showing some editable details on my aspx page.

I'm able to set `PopDelay` value from code behind.

But i need to set that value from `Client Side` using `java-script`.

Can any one tell me how can we set `PopDelay` value from client side.

### Edit-1

### Html markup

```
<div style="z-index:1000;float:right;padding-top:-2px;margin-top:-2px;">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSetting" ToolTip="Report setting"
        ImageUrl="~/GridViewCSSThemes/Images/Setting-icon.png" runat="server" OnClientClick="return false;" />
</div>
<asp:Panel ID="DropPanel" runat="server" style="display :none; 
        visibility: hidden;border:2px solid #E5E5E5;padding-bottom:-1px;background-color:#F5F5F5;
        margin-top:-28px;overflow:hidden;height:auto;max-height:700px;
        max-width:1000px;">
    <div class="rptHead">
        Report Setting:
        <div style="float:right;width:50px;margin-top:-10px;">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" ImageUrl="~/GridViewCSSThemes/Images/PinOff.png" runat="server" 
                Width="40px" Height="40px" onclick="imgbtn_Click" ToolTip="Pin/unpin setting panal"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    Rest of controls..........
</asp:Panel>  
<ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender OffsetY="25" OffsetX="35"
    ID="HoverMenuExtender1"  
    runat="server"  
    TargetControlID="btnSetting"  
    PopupControlID="DropPanel"  
    PopupPosition="Left"
    PopDelay="50" >  
</ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender>
```

Here `PopDelay=50`.
When user clicks on `imgbtn` i need to set `PopDelay` value to maximum.

Here i am able to set `PopDelay` from code behind but there is any way to set this value from client side when user clicks on `imgbtn`.

Comment: Show your markup with HoverMenuExtender and target control